# Passing functions as parameters

Tags: scala

I'm currently learning about higher-order functions and am trying to implement one.

```
def bigger(n: Integer, m: Integer):Integer={
    if(n>m) return n
    else return m
}

def bigT(t: Tuple3[Int, Int,(Int,Int)=>Int]): Integer={
    return t._3(t._1,t._2)
}

val tup=(5,2,bigger)
```

The second function receives a tuple containing two integers and the function that will be executed with them.

When I try to run this code (using ideone.com) receive the following error:

"missing arguments for method bigger in object Main;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
    val tup=(5,2,bigger)"

I want to pass the tuple named tup to the function bigT afterwards

Comment: Would it be more reasonable to define `bigT` with 3 parameters instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `Integer` and `Int`.

Try using `Int` everywhere:

```
def bigger(n: Int, m: Int) = if(n > m) n else m
def bigT(t: (Int, Int, (Int, Int) => Int)): Int = t._3(t._1, t._2)

val res = bigT((5, 2, bigger))  // 5
```

Comment: thanks!
just another question as I am new to scala: was the parameter declaration correct?
Can I write `t: Tuple3[Int, Int,(Int,Int)=>Int]` or is this wrong (I probably will omit the types wherever I can from now on to avoid mistakes anyway, but I think it is good if I know)

Comment: It is correct and equivalent but you usually never explicitly write ``TupleX`` and always use ``(a, b, ...)`` notation which is nicer

Comment: For this example, I'd suggest `def bigT(a: Int, b: Int, cmp: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = cmp(a, b)`. My opinion is that the `._1`, `._2` position methods to be noisy and hurt readability in this case.

Comment: Also, re: `I probably will omit the types wherever I can from now on to avoid mistakes anyway, but I think it is good if I know`. I would caution against this instinct. Types can provide helpful documentation - http://timperrett.com/2011/12/11/documenting-the-difficulties-of-documentation/.